# Does vector<string>** p = new vector<string> * [10]; make any sense in C++?

Tags: c++, string, pointers, vector

I have come across a code snippet.

It is a C++ exercise to judge **whether the define is right or illegal.**

```
vector<string>** p = new vector<string> * [10];
```

I think it is wrong because **lvalue declares p as pointer to pointer to vector of string.**

**rvalue is array of ten of pointer to vector of string.**

But the code compiles successfully without warning.

Does that definition make any sense?

Comment: What do you think of `int* array = new int[10];`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The declaration is legal and well-formed.**

`new T[...]` returns a `T*` pointer, where `T` in this case is `vector<string>*`. Thus, `new vector<string>*[...]` returns a `vector<string>**`, which is what `p` is declared as.

However, this kind of coding is also fairly useless in modern code, so no, it does not "make sense". It should be more like this instead:

`vector<vector<string>*> p(10);`

Or, more likely (assuming the individual `vector`s are going to be allocated with `new`):

`vector<std::unique_ptr<vector<string>>> p(10);`

But really, it should just be simply this:

`vector<vector<string>> p(10);`

And then, since a fixed length is being used, the outer `vector` should be changed to `std::array` instead:

`array<vector<string>, 10> p;`

*VERY RARELY* does it ever make sense to *dynamically* allocate standard C++ containers.